# plpgsql - syntax error at or near "if"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm struggling to get the syntax correct for a plpgsql if statement.

I'd like to use a different where clause depending on the value of the `m2` argument to the function.

But I get `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"`

```
create or replace function some_func(m1 int, m2 int)
returns table(match_id int) as
$$
begin
  return query
  select m.match_id from match as m
  if m2 < 1 then  -- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"
    where m.match_id > m1;
  else
    where m.match_id > m1 and m.match_id < m2;
  end if;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

The documentation says I should do

```
39.6.2.2. IF-THEN-ELSE

IF boolean-expression THEN
    statements
ELSE
    statements
END IF;
```

But it seems I've done that, so I must be misunderstanding some other aspect of how plpgsql works.

Comment: simply - you cannot mix SQL and PLPGSQL statements together. In your case, you try to mix two PL/pgSQL statements together RETURN QUERY and IF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a case statement there, rather than an if statement. For reference only, since it's a terrible query, it should look more like this:

```
return query
select m.match_id from match as m
 where case
       when m2 < 1 then m.match_id > m1
       else             m.match_id > m1 and m.match_id < m2
       end;
```

In your case just rewrite the query without the case:

```
return query
select m.match_id from match as m
 where m.match_id > m1
   and (m2 < 1 or m.match_id < m2);
```

Comment: There is no `if` construct in Postgres like there is in some other sql variants. Only `case`. There is an `if` in plpgsql, but it is used as a control structure, alongside `while`, `loop`, `for`, etc. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Yes, the places IF can be used was confusing me. Thanks for all your help.